# What is the object on the nose of this HondaJet in this marketing video?

Tags: nose, hondajet

In the [third Hondajet marketing video](http://www.hondajet.com/gallery-and-downloads/videos#3) there is a sword-like object visible on the nose of the aircraft.

What is this used for?

[image: still from Hondajet marketing video #3]

Comment: It is not sword like. Swords are flat with sharp edges while this pole is round.

Comment: Fair enough, but I didn't know a better way to describe it :)

Comment: Unfortunately the related question search is pretty poor as it is and poor wording does not exactly help. I am pretty sure there is a long answer somewhere describing where it is best to place the pitot tube and why, but it is unfortunately hard to find without remembering the exact words it uses.

Comment: @vvanscherpenseel "Spear like" would be the more accurate term.  At least if you want to stick i the realm of bronze age weapons... ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a [Pitot tube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitot_tube).

It is used to measure some air data values, depending on the model.

The most basic will measure only pressures (and then "derives" the velocity of the aircraft), the most advanced will measure angle of attack and sideslip as well.

The one in the photo is particularly long to make sure that is measuring values in the undisturbed airflow in front of the aircraft. It is a model usually seen in flight tests or on fighter aircraft.

In flight tests, because despite the accurate CFD modelling available today, uncertainties are still present during the first flights (that's why they are tests). The long probe gives a reference as much undisturbed as possible.

During normal operations you will generally find smaller probes, such as the ones found in [this](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/5009/1467) other question.

Fighter aircraft need the long boom for the reasons seen in [this](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/7457/1467) question.

Comment: Thanks for explaining! So it seems that footage from test flights was used in the marketing video :)

Comment: Alright, good point. I'll keep it mind for future questions.

Comment: @mins expanded a bit and pointed at the other questions on the topic

Comment: I've heard if you have a private jet you don't need a long probe

Comment: @TomMcW ? did I say you need it? if it is not private it is different? or if it not a jet? I fail to grasp the relevance of your statement.

Comment: @Federico You're missing the double entendre.

Comment: @TomMcW there's a reason for which people call me Sheldon.